# The name 'Message' does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#, asp.net

I keep getting the following error message at compile time:  "The name 'Message' does not exist in the current context".  All I'm trying to do is pop up a message box.  Here are my namespaces declared at the top of my code behind page:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Net.Mail;
```

And here is my code to show a message on a button click:

```
    protected void EmailAbout_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MailMessage myMessage = new MailMessage();
        myMessage.Subject = "Exception Handling Test";
        myMessage.Body = "Test message body";
        myMessage.From = new MailAddress("me@yourprovider.com");
        myMessage.To.Add(new MailAddress("you@yourprovider.com"));

        SmtpClient mySmtpClient = new SmtpClient();
        mySmtpClient.Send(myMessage);
        Message.Text = "Message sent";
    }
```

Is this a case of a missing namespace?  It seems so basic yet I can't figure it out?  Thanks in advance!

Here is the markup page:

```
<%@ Page Title="About SalesPro" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.master" AutoEventWireup="true"
CodeBehind="About.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication2.About" %>

<asp:Content ID="HeaderContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent">
</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">
    <h2>
        About, Inc.
    </h2>

    <p>
        Some Stuff here... 
    </p>

    <p>
        <asp:Button ID="EmailAbout" runat="server" Text="Email Information" 
            onclick="EmailAbout_Click" />
    </p>
</asp:Content>
```

Comment: What is `Message` supposed to be?

Comment: Do you have a control named `Message` on your page?

Comment: What is your last line of code?? where the **Message** is defined??

Comment: May be the label Message does not exists or not available at runtime

Comment: Paste a part of your markup, so we can see where is `Message` defined (as well as *what* it is)

Comment: Make sure that Code Behind Class is properly referenced from aspx page's Page directive and you don't have same class name implemented multiple times

Comment: I added the markup above - I am basically experimenting with sending emails and wanted to display a message box stating that the message was sent.  This code came from a ASP.NET 4 tutorial from Wrox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need the javaScript-function "alert()"  :-)

Try this:

```
RegisterStartupScript("alertBox1", "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Message sent');</script>");
```

Comment: This works and is probably the best multi-client way, but I was wondering what I am missing from doing it without Javascript?

Comment: JavaScript is the only way to popup interactive Boxes or something in browsers. Alternatively, you can use a label or a textBox for sending this results, thats works without JavaScript.

Comment: example to put the answer in the klicked button: EmailAbout.Text = "Mail Sent";

Answer (score 1):

I think The label Message is not available at run time or it does not exists

Updated Answer:

```
Response.Write("<script>alert('Message Sent');</script>");
```

Comment: How do you know it's a label?

Comment: bcz label has a text property. and there is a message "Message sent" by the user after sending an email. So I guess it. There is no need to vote down.

Comment: It wasn't a label that I was after, but rather showing a popup message on the screen.

Comment: where you have defined "Message" in the code ? Please add it to the code. Thanks

Comment: I haven't defined it.  Going through this tutorial in the ASP.NET 4 (Wrox) book, I don't see any definition of 'Message', so I assumed it was built into the language to be a way of showing message boxes much like an alert does in Jscript.  I'm getting the feeling it's not possible other than using Jscript?

Comment: Yes, the only way to show a message to the client is JavaScript or any Client Side Technology. Plz vote up to my answer people had done some -ve votes just bcz I assume you used a label.

Comment: @WaqarJanjua - thank you, Max explained this, too.  Javascript only if I want to pop up something :)

Comment: @AnthonyDarden You are Welcome. and Use JavaScript only when you don't want to access Server side ( Asp.net ) for e.g Validation, Simple calculation perform on the client side.

Answer (score 1):

**First right hand click on References add `System.Windows.Forms` then replace.**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Net.Mail;
```

**With**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Net.Mail;
using System.Windows.Forms;
```

Hope This Helps.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I've resolved this by placing my namespace directly into the c# (.cs) file that requires it. For some reason, adding it into app_code was not working, even though I've been able to pickup the namespace using intellisense.

ie

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Text;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;

public partial class SmartFutures_Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
...
...
     webMessageBox.Show("THANK YOU. YOUR REGISTRATION HAS BEEN SUBMITTED");
...
}

/// <summary>
/// A JavaScript alert class
/// </summary>
public static class webMessageBox
{

    /// <summary>
    /// Shows a client-side JavaScript alert in the browser.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="message">The message to appear in the alert.</param>
    public static void Show(string message)
    {
        // Cleans the message to allow single quotation marks
        string cleanMessage = message.Replace("'", "\\'");
        string wsScript = "<script type=\"text/javascript\">alert('" + cleanMessage + "');</script>";

        // Gets the executing web page
        Page page = HttpContext.Current.CurrentHandler as Page;

        // Checks if the handler is a Page and that the script isn't allready on the Page
        if (page != null && !page.ClientScript.IsClientScriptBlockRegistered("alert"))
        {
            //ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "MessageBox", wsScript, true);
            page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(typeof(webMessageBox), "alert", wsScript, false);
        }
    }
}
```